# Change axis limits in a surface plot

Tags: matlab

I'd like to make a surface plot of the matrix MAP_ob(2:7, 1:9) with the row two on top in the surface plot and row nine in the bottom, see code.

```
MAP_ob =   [1.4142    1.2020    1.0000    1.2020    1.4142    1.6664    1.9439       2.2361    2.5383    2.8483;
        1.2020         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0    1.0308;
        1.0000         0         0         0         0         0         0         0    1.0000    2.0000;
        1.2020         0         0    1.4142    0.6007         0         0         0    1.0401    2.0616;
        1.4142         0         0    1.8028    1.4142    0.8336    0.3884         0    1.0881    2.1360;
        1.6664         0         0    2.2361    1.6672    1.4142    0.9605    0.6007    1.4395    2.2361;
        1.9439         0         0    2.6926    1.9431    1.6008    1.4142    1.0416    1.9663    2.8302;
        2.2361         0         0    3.1623    2.2361    3.0048    1.5621    1.4142    2.4141    3.3336];    

ud = flipud(MAP_ob)
surface(ud)
```

This code  works as intended, however i want the limits:

```
xlim([0 9]); ylim([0 7]);
```

This makes the surface plot shift one row up and one column to the right. Is it possible to only manipulate the axis without having the whole plot "moved"?

Comment: Could you give a more detailed description of the expected outcome? (image would be the best) Do you want to change the axis tick labels?

Answer (score 0):

```
surface(0:size(ud,2)-1,0:size(ud,1)-1,ud);
```

Comment: please provide some more information with your code-snippet

Answer (score 0):

Nvm guys, this did the trick:

```
set(gca,'XTick',1:10);                          
set(gca,'YTick',1:8);
set(gca,'XTickLabel',0:9);
set(gca,'YTickLabel',0:7);
```